# Доступ к виджетам формы через слот Qt. Ничего не происходит, при изменении LineEdit через слот, что делать?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, сигналы-слоты

При попытке доступа к виджетам на форме через слот, то не происходит ничего. Возможно так и должно быть?

```
form.cpp
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"
#include<mainwindow.h>

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    MainWindow* m = new MainWindow;
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(send()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendData(QString)), m, SLOT(textchanged(QString)) );
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Form::send(){
    emit sendData(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<form.h>
#include<ui_form.h>.
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   // Form* form = new Form;
    connect(ui->pushButton , SIGNAL(clicked()) , this, SLOT(showadd()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::textchanged(QString data){
    ui->lineEdit->setText(data);
}
void MainWindow::showadd(){
     Form* form = new Form;
     form->show();
}
```

form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Form();
public slots:
    void send();
signals:
    void sendData(QString data);
private:
    Ui::Form *ui;
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void textchanged(QString data);
    void showadd();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: form.ui]

[image: mainwindow.ui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас каша с объектами. Не надо создавать объекты форм и окон внутри друг друга. Делайте так:

form.cpp

```
Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::Form) 
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(send()));
}

Form::~Form() {
    delete ui;
}

void Form::send() {
    emit sendData(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
signals:
    void showadd();
public slots:
    void textchanged(QString data);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton , SIGNAL(clicked()) , this, SIGNAL(showadd()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::textchanged(QString data){
    ui->lineEdit->setText(data);
}
```

А теперь все это связываем в main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "form.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    Form form;

    // Показать форму
    QObject::connect(&w, SIGNAL(showadd()), &form, SLOT(show()));
    // Передать данные из формы в главное окно
    QObject::connect(&form, SIGNAL(sendData(QString)), &w, SLOT(textchanged(QString data)));

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```